# Add Google Maps to my website with a search box and markers (on click) and get lat & long in html input boxes

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My_Google_Maps</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 300px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      .pac-container {
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #type-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #type-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
      }

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=My_API_Key&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to add google map to my website with a search box (that shows the searched address on the map with a marker (balloon)) and also we can click anywhere in the map (the previous marker must be gone at the click and the  marker will came at the clicked position (means only one marker should be appear on the map)).
Also i want to get the current latitude and longitude (of the current marker's exact position) into two different input boxes respectively.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Google has plenty of examples in their documentation to get you started, start [there](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/).

Comment: Dear Sir, as u asked me for the work i've done..i attach a html code which just add google map and a search box but no markers were their and no geolocation coordinates...actually i'm a newbie in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 12
    });
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397,150.644);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: myLatlng,
        draggable: true,
        icon: mapIcon
    });

 var input = (document.getElementById('pac-input'));
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function () {
       
       
        marker.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }

        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(12);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
        }


        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);

        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
                (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
        }

        //infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
        infowindow.setContent(address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
   $('#latitude').val(place.geometry.location.lat());
   $('#longitude').val(place.geometry.location.lng());
      
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.20&sensor=false"></script>
<div id="myMap"></div>
<input type="text" name="delivery_location"  placeholder="" class="form-control" id="pac-input" required>

<input type="hidden" id="latitude" placeholder="Latitude" name="latitude"/>
<input type="hidden" id="longitude" placeholder="Longitude" name="longitude"/>
```